# Writing a program which uses TTS (text-to-speech) where should I start?

Tags: java, c, text-to-speech

Can anyone tell where to find instruction to add TTS to Java written program *(C is suitable to)*. I wold like to write program without any illustration and add some features that any existing program does not have. User just writes word and computer pronounce it loudly. It would be good if the voices output is good not like most TTS has. **Can anyone help me**.

I am new in Java and C so is there any instructions how to include tts to my program.

I know about Java: FreeTTS but I have not found any good tutorials how to include it to my program *(use it in my program)* or how to write a program what uses Java: FreeTTS

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous libraries for both languages, for example:

Java: [FreeTTS](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php)

C++: [Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/)